# How does automatic redirection for the redirection plugin work?

Tags: plugins, redirect

I am experimenting with the [Redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) and I really like it so far, but I can't figure out how automatic redirections work. If you go to the options section there is this section:

URL Monitoring - You can have Redirection detect changes in URLs and have an automatic redirection created in a specific group.

However, I can't seem to trigger this. What I would expect is that manually modifying the slug or changing my permalink structure would trigger the creation of the automatic redirects. However this doesn't happen. Does anyone have experience with this plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Check redirection/models/monitor.php

It's pretty simple to follow whats doing.